# How to unload an overlay without clicking a close button after pin check

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, overlay

I have a page when opening an overlay is loading and asking for pin validation. pin check is via php on action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
This works all fine, but I have no idea how to close the overlay automaticly after the pin is correct. I have no problems showing a close button to click, but I want it automaticaly...

the script is:

```
<script>
function on() {document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";}

function off() {document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";} 
</script>
```

**I can close it in php with this BUT how can i do it automaticaly?**

```
  <body class="page" onLoad="on();" >

<!--##################################### -->
<!--##### OVERLAY ####################### -->
<!--##################################### -->   
<div id="overlay" >
<div id="suche">


<form class="was-validated" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" autocomplete="off" id="buchen2">

<div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
                <label for="usr">Enter Security PIN<div class="toolitip"> <a class="fa fa-info-circle" style="color: blue;"></a><span class="toolitiptext">Please enter your security PIN. If you do not have a PIN, ask the administrator! </span></div></label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pin" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" onChange="submit();" required>
            </div>
</div>
</form>
<?      
include('db.php');
?>

<?
$pin = $_POST["pin"];
$ergebnis = $dbconnection->query("select usr, pin from user where usr = '$user' limit 1")
                        or die($dbconnection->error);
while($row = $ergebnis->fetch_object()){
    
    $pinD=$row->pin;
}
    if ($pin == $pinD) {
 echo "<script>
function off() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}       
</script>"; 
echo "<p> Code is good! Please close the Overlay to continue </p>";
echo "<button type='button' onclick='off()' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' name='erledigt'>CLOSE and continue</button>  ";

 echo "<script>
 off();
</script>";

 echo "<script>
function off() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}       
</script>"; 


    }
    
    else {
        echo "<p> You must enter the correct code</p>";
    }
?>

</div>  
</div>
<!--##################################### -->
<!--##### OVERLAY ####################### -->
<!--##################################### -->
```

Unload the overlay automatical in the php if syntax.
I can only use onclick="off" but how can I run the "off" without clicking?

Comment: PHP runs on the server. So you either make PHP echo a `<script` block  which runs the off() function (e.g. `echo "<script>off();>/script>";`, or you could think about doing the check via AJAX instead and then using JS to set the overlay when it receives the AJAX response

Comment: P.S. Your SQL seems inefficient. Why do you fetch all rows which have a similar name to the $user variable (and why not an exact match??) and _then_ check the PIN? Why not just add another element to the `WHERE` clause to check the PIN directly? And then PHP can see if the query returned any rows or not. That would be much more efficient.

Comment: @ADyson thx for your comment - I tried this again, but the overlay will not disapear. It only disapears when I do it with the onclick='off();'

Comment: `the overlay will not disapear`...did you check that PHP echoed the script successfully? Did you check it was output _after_ wherever the `off()` function is defined? Did you check for browser errors in the console? Did you use the JS debugger to see if the `off` function was actually executed? Bear in mind I can only make a suggestion based on a tiny snippet of your code, so it's not intended as a full solution. You may need to do work to integrate it, and if it doesn't immediately work then you'll need to do work to debug that. But the basic concept of what I've suggested should be correct.

Comment: @Bernhard Is there any JavaScript involved sending the form? If so, please include it in your question. If not: Why do you output an overlay that needs to be closed anyways?

Comment: @ADyson I know you should be right and it sounds all good to me, but... :(
console has no errors - script is echoed correct... strange I know...
I start the overlay like this:

 <body class="page" onLoad="on();" >

is this maybe the problem? All works fine when I use the onclick='off();' function but not auto...

Comment: @volkerschulz thx for thinking about - no javascript - i put in the whole problem code again... I use the overlay to check a pin to continue. I know i could use this check as an additional webpage, but this looks so nice to me :) maybe I am totally wrong with this idea..

Comment: I updated the code and put the full overlay code in - thx to all for thinking about!!

Comment: off() runs first, before on(), because the call to on() waits until the whole page has loaded, whereas off() runs immediately when your script is placed on the page. So the effect of your off() call is immediately negated.

Comment: P.S. I don't know why your code is defining the off() function twice more, when it was already defined in your page previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see what you need javascript for. Just execute the PHP logic first and then either output the overlay (if no PIN entered or wrong PIN entered) or don't (if PIN was ok).

**Option 1: No JS**

```php
<?php
$pin_ok = false;
$pin_checked = false;

if(isset($_POST['pin'])) {
    // Is form submit
    $pin_checked = true;
    if($_POST['pin'] == '12345') {
        // PIN ok
        $pin_ok = true;
    } 
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="page">
    <?php if(!$pin_ok) { ?>
    <!--##################################### -->
    <!--##### OVERLAY ####################### -->
    <!--##################################### -->   
    <div id="overlay" >
        <div id="suche">


            <form class="was-validated" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" id="buchen2">

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
                        <label for="usr">Enter Security PIN<div class="toolitip"> <a class="fa fa-info-circle" style="color: blue;"></a><span class="toolitiptext">Please enter your security PIN. If you do not have a PIN, ask the administrator! </span></div></label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pin" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" onChange="submit();" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php
                if($pin_checked) {
                    // This happens only if wrong PIN was submitted
                    echo "<p>You must enter the correct code</p>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <!--##################################### -->
    <!--##### OVERLAY ####################### -->
    <!--##################################### -->
    <?php } //if(!$pin_ok) ?>
    [...] REST OF YOUR CONTENT HERE [...]
</body>
</html>
```

If you have some other reason why to use javascript, read on. When loading your page, the overlay has a defined state, it is either hidden or shown. I'm assuming it is shown by default. So there's no need to call `on()` `onload`, you just need to call `off()` if PIN was ok.

**Option 2: With JS**

```php
<?php
$pin_ok = false;
$pin_checked = false;

if(isset($_POST['pin'])) {
    // Is form submit
    $pin_checked = true;
    if($_POST['pin'] == '12345') {
        // PIN ok
        $pin_ok = true;
    } 
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="page">
    <!--##################################### -->
    <!--##### OVERLAY ####################### -->
    <!--##################################### -->   
    <div id="overlay" >
        <div id="suche">


            <form class="was-validated" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" id="buchen2">

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
                        <label for="usr">Enter Security PIN<div class="toolitip"> <a class="fa fa-info-circle" style="color: blue;"></a><span class="toolitiptext">Please enter your security PIN. If you do not have a PIN, ask the administrator! </span></div></label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pin" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" onChange="submit();" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php
                if($pin_checked && !$pin_ok) {
                    // This happens only if wrong PIN was submitted
                    echo "<p>You must enter the correct code</p>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <!--##################################### -->
    <!--##### OVERLAY ####################### -->
    <!--##################################### -->
    [...] REST OF YOUR CONTENT HERE [...]
    <script>
        function on() {
            document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
        }

        function off() {
            document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
        }
        <?php
        if($pin_checked && $pin_ok) {
            // This happens only if correct PIN was submitted
            echo "off();";
        }
        ?>
    </script>
    <hr />
    <button onclick="on();">Show</button><button onclick="off();">Hide</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**P.S.:** @ADyson already mentioned in the comments that your SQL statement and the verification is overly complicated. You would so something like

```
SELECT usr FROM user WHERE usr='$user' AND pin='$pin'
```

and then check if you have any results (having results = PIN ok). Your code doesn't show where the `$user` is coming from, but you get the idea. **Important:** Don't forget to sanitize the input, use `real_escape_string()` or `bind_param()`.

Comment: MANY thx to you!!!!! thanke you very much!!! WOW - I finally made it!!!!!